# Use Override functions(GetHashCode) from Library Collections(HashSet) with an interface type parameter

Tags: c#, interface, hashset, hashcode

I have interface Rotation. Implemented by class QuarterRotation:

```
public interface Rotation {
     bla...
}
```

And an implementation:

```
public class QuarterRotation: Rotation,  IEquatable<QuarterRotation>{
     constructor etc.. bla...
     public override GetHashCode() {
        return [nice number to describe equality]
     }
     public override Equals(QuarterRotation other) {
        return [equal when direction and rotation amount is equal]
     }
}
```

No I want to put it in a HashSet like this, but equality does not hold:

```
var set = new HashSet<Rotation>() {new QuarterRotation(x,0)};
set.Contains(new QuarterRotation(x,0)); // should be true in my mind, but is false
```

This is due to my custom overriden GetHashCode and Equals not being called instead the Object version is called.

This does work:

```
var set = new HashSet<QuarterRotation>() {new QuarterRotation(x,0)};
set.Contains(new QuarterRotation(x,0)); // is true
```

But this is not my dream. Because I don't want to commit to one kind of Rotation. Is there a possibility in C# how I can use an interface like this for HashSet? I feel the practical problem I understand but if I'm wrong please correct me. Also further explanation on why it might be sensible to think differently for resolving such collections from an abstract point of view, at least in C# is appreciated.

Comment: Why does your class implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`? It doesn't implement the members of this interface. Did you mean `IEquatable<T>`?

Comment: You should also override `Equals(object)`

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't clear. `HashSet<T>` will use the default equality comparer, `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. If your type implements `IEquatable<T>`, then this will call the `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` method, otherwise it will call `object.Equals(object)` (this is only to avoid boxing if `T` is a value type). If you implement your own equality you *must* override `object.Equals(object)`. There's really little point in implementing `IEquatable<T>` unless `T` is a value type, but if you do, `object.Equals(object)` would normally call `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)`

Comment: @canton7 yes thank you, it should be equatable

Comment: @canton7 oh nice, definitely forgot to implement override Equals(object), thought the interface would cover me... I'll put it in, see if you made my dreams come true!

Comment: @KlausGütter overriding equals(object) fixes it, closing the question, thnx!

Comment: This doesn't even compile, and there in also lies your confusion. `public override bool Equals(QuarterRotation other)` the `override` there is not valid (the `QuarterRotation` parameter is unique for this version, there is no base method that takes a `QuarterRotation` to override. So as the `HashSet<Rotattion>` doesn't know anything about a `QuarterRotation` the specific `Equals(QuarterRotation other)` can never be called (there also isn't a guarantee that `other` also is a `QuarterRotation`) so it falls back to `Equals(object other)`.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing Equals(Object obj) with override option in QuarterRotation fixes it, that makes HashSet use that function. It is completely seperate from the Interface given in the HashSet type parameter(I assume it finds the Equals method of the function at runtime). Thnx @canton7 and @Klausgutter